# handle multiple change events angular4

Tags: angular

When adding a few $events I am having trouble retaining the previous values from other filters.

inside my Component.ts

```
   handleMemberListChange(value) {
    this.getMappSummaryStatistics = new MappSummaryStatistics();
    this.summaryStatisticsService.getMappSummaryStatistics(value.number, ???)
      .subscribe(res => this.getMappSummaryStatistics = res);
  }
  handleTimeListChange(value) {
    this.getMappSummaryStatistics = new MappSummaryStatistics();
    this.summaryStatisticsService.getMappSummaryStatistics(???, value.timeType)
      .subscribe(res => this.getMappSummaryStatistics = res);
  }
```

for example:

**handleMemberListChange** I select **foo1** and it takes the params and changes the data.

**handleTimeListChange** I select **poo2** but handleMemberListChange no longer has **foo1** as the value for passed into **handleMemberListChange** , it just nulls it out.

Comment: Why would you expect it to still have `foo1`?  It is scoped separately.  If you need to retain the value, you should consider storing it in your component instance or in global state so that it is then accessible later.

Comment: That makes complete sense. I am just unsure how store it in the instance.

Comment: I'm not sure how to help you since I don't understand your example above.  But I should expect you'd be able to create a private instance in your component `private foo1 : Foo;` that you would populate when the value changes: `this.foo1 = value;`

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on what David L said, you can do the following to store the value of `foo1`:

```
private foo: Foo;

handleMemberListChange(value) {
  this.foo = value;
  // ... rest of the method
}
```

But based on your code and question, I'm guessing this is what you're trying to achieve:

```
private foo: Foo;

handleMemberListChange(value) {
  this.foo.number = value.number; // set number
  this.getMappSummaryStatistics = new MappSummaryStatistics();
  this.summaryStatisticsService.getMappSummaryStatistics(value.number, ???)
    .subscribe(res => this.getMappSummaryStatistics = res);
}
handleTimeListChange(value) {
  this.foo.timeType = value.timeType; // set timeType
  this.getMappSummaryStatistics = new MappSummaryStatistics();
  this.summaryStatisticsService.getMappSummaryStatistics(???, value.timeType)
    .subscribe(res => this.getMappSummaryStatistics = res);
}
```

This way, the values of your "filters" get stored and can be used later on.